# Flasher unit to PCB socket mount

Tags: pcb, relay

I’m making an automotive circuit using a third party flasher unit such as [this one](https://www.rotatingelectrics.co.uk/2-pin-flasher-unit-relay-indicators-12v-84w-light-turn-signal-wood-auto-flh1001h).

I feel these units can be a source of failure so I want to be able to remove and replace a faulty unit a few years down the line if necessary.

Do they follow some kind of standards with a possibility of a PCB mount socket to mount it? How would you mount these on a PCB?

Comment: Those connection are made to be wired, why don't you use that?

Comment: Most automotive applications have moved away from mechanical relays in the flashers specifically for failure reasons. Why don't you want to use something solid-state?

Comment: I wanted neat board without too many hanging cables, and some solid state flasher unit come in the same package. I may design a solid-state flasher unit within my board then...

Answer (score 0):

The flasher unit being referred to is quite big (30mm φ x 30mm long) and intended for clamp mounting (not on a PCB).

Also, the high current wire connections are to be made using 'Lucar' connectors.

[image]

It would be easier to replace it if it were to be mounted and wired as intended.